# Moving from a login Storyboard to the main Storyboard in Swift without Warning

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, storyboard

I am trying to change view controller after a user logs into my app from the login storyboard to my main storyboard, this works successfully but I receive the following warning in the console:

```
2016-02-05 01:57:59.553 Commu[4749:160489] Warning: Attempt to present <UITabBarController: 0x7f93285b9d90> on <Commu.LoginViewController:     0x7f9328494e80> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

The code in my login view controller is as follows:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
   let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
   let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainMenu")
   self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)                         
})
```

Is there a better way to move between storyboards to avoid this warning message?

Comment: How are you setting up your login storyboard? Is that also in a modal?

Comment: The login page is the initial view controller of the loginSystem storyboard, on this page you can login with your username and password. The user information is then check against firebase and provide errors if the information is incorrect or sent them to the main menu if the information is correct

Answer (score 0):

**Once user login, login hierarchy no more required.**

**After successful login your need to change root view controller of your mainWindow, i.e. rootViewContoller of window of appDelegate.**

Similarly change the rootViewContoller of window again when user logout.

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainMenu")


let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = vc
```

You can also include UINavigationController in hierarchy, to push and pop other viewControllers.

Comment: thanks but I am still receiving the same error:          2016-02-05 13:30:20.183 Commu[2277:865191] Warning: Attempt to present <UITabBarController: 0x154f62790> on <Commu.LoginViewController: 0x154d41b20> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Answer (score 0):

The warning is because:

`self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)` is presenting the viewController as a modal view. Which should only be used to display a screen for a short period of time to give the user some actions. It is intended that the user will, at some point, move back from the modal window.

There is a new feature, called a [storyboard reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_storyboard/Chapters/AddSBReference.html). This allows you to use a segue between storyboards.

Then you could use:

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueId", sender: self)
```

This is a much cleaner way to do it and keeps all your navigation controls inside the storyboard.

Comment: Thanks, how can I programmatically create the segue as I still want to do a user authentication check before sending the user to a new storyboard? and is their a solution which works with ios versions lower than 9